# Which event of Page I can access the value of hiddenfield initialize in document. ready function inasp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I set some hidden filed value in document.ready function In which event of page life cycle I cant access the value of that hidden filed here is Code

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    StatdIds = $("input[id$=hdnSelectedStateIDs]").val();
    $("input[id$=hdnSupplierID]").val($("input[id$=hdnSupplierID]").val());
    $("input[id$=hdnShippinRateID]").val($("input[id$=hdnShippingId]").val());
    $("body").click(function (e) {
        if (e.target.id != 'dvNewPostSettings-ddlFilter') {
            $("#dvNewPostSettings-dvSearchFilterActions").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

and Page Code is

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim supplierID As Integer = hdnSupplierID.Value
    Dim ShippingRateID As Integer = hdnShippinRateID.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: I think all server events will fire first (page lifecycle) and after that your client side event(document.ready) will fire. You can not access value of hidden field in page lifecycel events that you set in document.ready. However you can access the value if you fire some server side event after setting the value.

Comment: Is there are any way to access hidden field in code behind file that I access in document.ready.function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have used something like below:

```
<div id="div<%= Test %>">
</div>
```

Declare one property in your page like:

```
public string Test { get; set; }
```

and assign value in Page_Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Test = "Hello World";
            }
        }
```

Run the page and you can see in rendered page the id of the div is changed to "divHello World".

So you can not access the value of hidden field that you set in document.ready as it fires once all the page life cycle events are fired.

Comment: Is there are any way to access hidden field in code behind file that I access in document.ready function.

Comment: You can fire button click event and access the value you set in document.ready.